# Flutter_typehead: BoxConstraints not applying maxWidth on SuggestionsBoxDecoration

Tags: flutter, typehead

I'm using this package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_typeahead.
I'm trying to limit the suggestions' box width size using BoxConstraints, but it doesn't work. 
This is my code:

```
 return TypeAheadFormField(
    textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
      controller: _typeAheadController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: _icon,
          hintText: _hintText),
    ),
    suggestionsCallback: (String pattern) async {
      return suggestions;
    },
    itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
      if (suggestions.isNotEmpty)
            ListTile(
              title: Text(suggestion),
            );
    },suggestionsBoxDecoration: SuggestionsBoxDecoration(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 10, maxHeight: 10)
  ),
    onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
      this._typeAheadController.text = suggestion;
    },
    hideOnEmpty: true,
  );
```

The constraints on height are working, but on width not.

Comment: I think you can ask this on their thread by filling an issue.

Comment: Yes, they will fix it soon. Thanks!